# Save results of sub string function in R data set as a vector or array

Tags: arrays, r, vector, substring

I have a string column. I need to create an array of words by splitting string by " " (space). The code below works fine for single cell

```
array(strsplit(f2$standard_address[1], " ")[[1]] )
```

I want to do this for an entire column. I tried few apply function but not able to store them.

Can you help me create a vector field and store results there?

Comment: `strsplit` is vectorized, no need for `sapply` or `lapply` Does `strsplit(f2$standard_address, ' ')` produce desired output?

Comment: Remember when posting a question that it's often very useful [to provide a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).